# Maddening Python For Loop

Tags: python

I am writing a simple checkers program. I am trying to get a nice ASCII output of the game state. Here is the function I am trying to use:

```
 def function(self):
     board =  [["+", " - "]*8 + ["+", "\n"], \
               ["|", "   "]*8 + ["|", "\n"]]*8 + \
              [["+", " - "]*8 + ["+", "\n"]]

     i = 0
     for row in self.state:
         j = 0
         for cell in row:
             if cell == WHITE:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' w '
             elif cell == WHITE_KING:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' W '
             elif cell == BLACK:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' b '
             elif cell == BLACK_KING:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' B '
             j += 1
         i += 1

     return board
```

(outside the class definition):

```
EMPTY, WHITE, WHITE_KING, BLACK, BLACK_KING = range(5)
```

I cannot see what is wrong with it, yet here is what is happening.

```
>>> B = CheckerBoard()
>>> B.state
[[3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3], [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
>>> print("".join(map(lambda x: "".join(x), B.function())))
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w | w | w | w | w | w | w | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
```

The desired output is

```
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| b |   | b |   | b |   | b |   |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
|   | b |   | b |   | b |   | b |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| b |   | b |   | b |   | b |   |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w |   | w |   | w |   | w |   |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
|   | w |   | w |   | w |   | w |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
| w |   | w |   | w |   | w |   |
+ - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
```

**EDIT**: For those who get stuck in a similar place, here is the working solution:

```
def function(self):
     board =  [x for list in
               [[[a for subl in [["+", " - "] for _ in range(8)] for a in subl] + ["+", "\n"], \
                [a for subl in [["|", "   "] for _ in range(8)] for a in subl] + ["|", "\n"]] \
                 for _ in range(8)] for x in list] + \
              [[a for subl in [["+", " - "] for _ in range(8)] for a in subl] + ["+", "\n"]]

     i = 0
     for row in self.state:
         j = 0
         for cell in row:
             if cell == WHITE:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' w '
             elif cell == WHITE_KING:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' W '
             elif cell == BLACK:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' b '
             elif cell == BLACK_KING:
                 board[2*i+1][2*j+1] = ' B '
             j += 1
         i += 1

     return board
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Include that for clarity..

Comment: More importantly, what's the _input_? Are you sure that `self.state` isn't all `WHITE` cells, because of a bug in the code you haven't shown us? Also, can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a code fragment that can't be run or debugged on its own?

Comment: Does the *8 expressions in that board declaration create 8 distinct copies of the lists inside, or 8 references to the same lists?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: 8 references to the same list. Which is _probably_ the problem—but only if the last row actually is supposed to be all `w` values; otherwise, the problem is most likely caused by doing something similar in constructing `self.state` in the first place (although he'd still have to fix this problem after fixing that one anyway).

Comment: Just for kicks, what is the return value of B.function()?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Wait, I didn't read his code carefully enough; it's not _just_ that he's creating 8 references to the same list, it's that the list itself has 8 references to the same sub-list, so he only needs one `w` value, not a whole row of them, to get this result.

Comment: Well this is just hilarious. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common mistake. `list*N` does a shallow copy, e.g. in `x = …; l = [x]*4` the `l` is the same as `l = [x,x,x,x]`. Now if `x` is a list, then you edit the references in multiple places.

See [How do I create a multidimensional list?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) in the official Python FAQ for more details. But the short version is: instead of `[x]*4`, write `[x for _ in range(4)]`, and you'll get four separate copies of `x` instead of four references to the same `x`.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to fix it (e.g., use `[x for _ in range(4)]` instead of `[x]*4`). But it probably does identify his problem.